# Get latitude and longitude of user in PHP or JavaScript for use in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, geolocation

I have an Android app which gets the user's location (latitude and longitude). The latitude and longitude is used to query a database via a web service.

I am in the process of developing a website which will be another gateway into the backend. In order to make the website useful I need to get the latitude and longitude of the user, as the results are sorted by distance (i.e. distance from user's location to location of returned data which is a bar/restaurant).

So how do I get the latitude and longitude of the user?

Comment: I added a couple of relevant tags.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible via PHP directly although if you are creating a website you can use the javascript geolocation API to query the browser about what it knows about the users current location:

```
<script>
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
function getLocation() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
    } else {
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}
function showPosition(position) {
    x.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + position.coords.latitude +     "<br>Longitude: " + position.coords.longitude;
    } 
</script>
```

I have simply copied the code example from w3 schools vertabrim.

Source:

[http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp)